# x64dbg: is there a way to save the complete disassembly of a module to a text file?

Tags: disassembly, x64dbg

Is it possible to save the complete disassembly / listing to a file, and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

From the disassembly window:

1. Choose the start of your data that you want to copy

   [image]
2. Use the mouse wheel or trackpad to go up or down in the disassembly window

   > you can also use the arrow keys <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> but you need to Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> first.

   [image]
3. Press `Shift` and then choose the end of the data that you want to copy, this will highlight the data from the first line you choose till the last line you stopped at.
4. Above the highlighted data that you want to copy, <kbd>right click</kbd> and select <kbd>copy</kbd> -> <kbd>Selection</kbd> or <kbd>Selection to File</kbd>

   [image]
5. This is the result

   [image]